# Missing data when importing Excel file into DataGridView

Tags: c#, database, excel, datagridview

I'm having a problem importing data from `.csv` / Excel file into a datagridview.

In my `.csv` file there is a date column like `27/01/2017`, and when I'm importing the data into my datagridview, it's working fine, but only 12 rows from the date column are transferred. There are 3-4 records missing in the date column in the datagridview.

I have tried already IMAX=1 and ACE and it doesn't change anything. But when I'm changing the date column to something else (not date), the import works fine, it seems the problem is to import dates.

This is my code for importing the data from the `.csv` / Excel file:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    try
    {
        string Pathconn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Pathconn);
        OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + SheetName + "$]", conn);

        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        myDataAdaptor.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("no workbook was uploaded please upload again!");
        wb.Close(false);
        excel.Quit();
    }

    wb.Close(false);
    excel.Quit();
}
```

If someone can help me solve this problem please, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the data is not formatted correctly in Excel. Confirm that this correct, and try something like what you see below.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
            System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
            MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\csharp.net-informations.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
            MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection);
            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com");
            DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
            MyConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```